# Sitemesh 2.4.2: How to use decorators other than body decorator

Tags: jsp, struts2, sitemesh

I am using `struts2-archetype-starter` maven template to create Struts2 webapp. Though, I used Struts2 before, I am new to Sitemesh. I have one `adminTemplate.jsp` in my `decorator` folder, containing one

`<decorator:body />`

tag. As we know, body is not the only thing we might want to customize, I need some custom **scripts** in my page. `<decorator:body />` comes above footer (not very good place your scripts).

I also tried to refer to the docs provided by sitemesh, here:-

http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Passing+Additional+Elements+to+the+Decorator

But, unfortunately, the page is not having any text at all.

Can anybody please tell me how to achieve the same? It will be very helpful if anybody can leave pointers to some good docs as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can insert the **head** placeholder in the adminTemplate.jsp

```html
<head>
  <title>
    <decorator:title/>
  </title>
  ...
  ...
  <decorator:head/>
</head>
```

then custom **scriptes** in your pages.

```html
<head>
  <title>
    page1
  </title>
  <script>
    ....
  </script>
</head>
```